# What are good sources for Lamplighter's Beeswax?

Tags: fallen-london

Occasionally I find myself running out of Lamplighter's Beeswax in Fallen London.  It happened recently, and I didn't remember a good source for more.  What are good places to look for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are A Person of Some Importance, the most efficient source is via 'A lovely thought' in Ladybones Road, Unfinished Business. If you're at sea, you'll pick some up as you explore Bullbone Island.

Of course, you can just buy it from the Bazaar.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to access is probably "The Chandleress's Complaint - Light a Candle and Wait." In the Department of Menace on Watchmaker's Hill.

Here's a complete list, blatantly ripped from the [Fallen London wiki](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Lump_of_Lamplighter_Beeswax_Sources):

'Oi! You stepped on my invisible rat!'
  A lovely thought
  Explore that mysterious hollow
  Have the Talkative Rat ask the Big Rat's guards
  Hire some help and strip the place bare
  Light a candle, and wait
  Loot the bodies
  Merrigans Exchange
  Sigh and sell off the ratskin suit
  Soft soles and a mask
  Something dark
  Trade jade for relics
  Wild bees